# kivy screen freeze when run speech recognition function

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to both functions working on same time. I click the `START` button it will recognize the voice, and out(screen) button is shows the text out put ...but the problem is  when I click the start button it recognizes the voices and screen was freeze I can't press the out(screen)button. I want run the recognize function for recognizing the voice and out(screen) for display the text out put.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
import speech_recognition as sr
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

Window.size=(300,500)

class Menuscreen(Screen):
    pass

class ButtonONEScreen(Screen):
    pass
class MopScreen(Screen):
    pass


# kivy code 

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

    Menuscreen:
    ButtonONEScreen:
    MopScreen:

<Menuscreen>:
    name:"menu" 
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'ButtonONE'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'ONE'
<ButtonONEScreen>:
    name: 'ONE'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'START'
        id: START_button
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2,'center_y':0.1}
        on_release:
            app.voice2text()
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'back'
        id: back
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_release:
            root.manager.current="menu"

   MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'out'
        id: START_button
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.1}
        on_release:
        app.text()
            root.manager.current= "mainout"
 <MopScreen>:
       name: "mainout"
       MDLabel:
           id: mylabel
           size:self.texture_size
           size_hint_y: None

       MDRectangleFlatButton:
           text: 'back'
           id: back
           pos_hint: {'center_x':0.7,'center_y':0.1}
           on_release:
               root.manager.current="menu"
"""

# python code

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "v2t App"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

   def build(self):
        sm = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return sm

   def voice2text(self):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        while True:
            while True:
                with sr.Microphone() as source:
                audio = r.listen(source,10,4)
            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                print(text)
                file=open("words.txt","a")
                file.write(text +"\n")
                file.close()
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                print(" ")
            except sr.RequestError as e:
                print(" ")

    def text(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.callback, 0.5)

    def callback(self, dt):
        file= open("words.txt" , "r")
        load_file = ""
        for line in file:
            load_file = load_file + line
            file.close()
        self.root.get_screen("out").ids.mylabel.text =str(load_file)

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: you will have to run it in separated `thread`.

Comment: Separately it will worked but I want working simultaneously (recognizing and text out put(onather screen) working in my app what  I to do

Comment: you have to use thread to work simultaneously.

Comment: I trying to do that but I got an error Iam new to kivy can u please help me to edit my code to do that

Comment: if you tried it the show this code in question, and show FULL error message. And we may try to fix it. We can't read in your mind and you have to show all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: Yeah ok ... How to run 2buttons (those are having infinity loop functions ) simultaneously in kivy

Comment: I will try to create version with theading. But I don't understand why you use file to write and later read data - you could use `self.` to have access to data in all functions without using file.

Comment: to lead all file you can do `load_file = file.read()` without `for`-loop. And it gives string in variables load_file so you don't have to use `str()` in line with `str(load_file)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is example which uses `threading` to run function with `speech_recognition`.

I made few other changes. I keep words in variable `self.words` so I can access them in other functions - so I don't have to write and read it again. But I also update `mainout` directly in thread - so I don't need `Clock` to do it.

When it recognizes word then it writes all words to file - so I can read them again when I start program again.

BTW: I had to use `0` in `sr.Microphone(0)` to run code with my external microphone. I added code with `sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()` to display numbers for all microphones.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

import speech_recognition as sr

import threading

Window.size = (300, 500)

class Menuscreen(Screen):
    pass

class ButtonONEScreen(Screen):
    pass
class MopScreen(Screen):
    pass

# kivy code 

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

    Menuscreen:
    ButtonONEScreen:
    MopScreen:

<Menuscreen>:
    name: 'menu'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Button ONE'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'ONE'
        
<ButtonONEScreen>:
    name: 'ONE'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        id: START_button
        text: 'START'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.2, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release:
            app.voice2text()
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        id: back_button
        text: 'back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        id: out_button
        text: 'out'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'mainout'
            
<MopScreen>:
    name: 'mainout'
    MDLabel:
        id: out_label
        size: self.texture_size
        size_hint_y: None

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        id: back
        text: 'back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
"""

# python code

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "v2t App"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.thread = None  # to check if thread is already created
        
        # read words at start ; catch error if file doesn't exist yet
        try:
            with open('words.txt') as fh:
                self.words = fh.read().splitlines()
                Clock.schedule_once(self.init_ui)  # `ids` doesn't exist yet, so it has to run it later
        except Exception as ex:
            print('[__init__] Exception:', ex)
            self.words = []
        print('[__init__] words:', self.words)
        
    def build(self):
        sm = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return sm

    def init_ui(self, dt=0):
        # display words from file 
        text = '\n'.join(self.words)
        self.root.get_screen("mainout").ids.out_label.text = text  # `mainout` instead `out`; without `str()`

    def voice2text(self):
        if not self.thread:
            print('[voice2text] starting thread')
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.recognize_words)  # function's name without ()
            self.thread.daemon = True  # kill thread at the end of program
            self.thread.start()
        else:
            print('[voice2text] thread is already running')
        
    def recognize_words(self):
        # display all devices
        for number, item in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
            print(f'device index: {number:2} | name: {item}')
            
        r = sr.Recognizer()

        while True:
            try:
                with sr.Microphone(0) as source:
                    audio = r.listen(source, 10, 4)
                text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                print('[recognize_words] text:', text)
                self.words.append(text)
                text = '\n'.join(self.words)
                self.root.get_screen("mainout").ids.out_label.text = text  # `mainout` instead `out`; without `str()`
                # write all words when new word
                with open('words.txt', 'w') as fh:
                    fh.write(text)
            except sr.UnknownValueError as ex:
                print("[recognize_words] UnknownValueError:", ex)
            except sr.RequestError as e:
                print("[recognize_words] RequestError:", ex)
            except sr.WaitTimeoutError as ex:
                print("[recognize_words] WaitTimeoutError:", ex)

TestApp().run()
```